# Excel выбор листа при импорте laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделал выборку листов при импорте из Excel файла в бд laravel.
На данный момент мой импорт:

```
$data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
})->get();
```

Дальше перебираем `$data` и добавляем в бд, но переборка уже происходит на 1 листе, как указать например второй лист?

```
foreach ($data as $object) {
  //$object->name....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
})->get();
$pages = $data->all();
```

Сейчас в `$pages` уже лежат листы, соответственно `$pages[0]` - первый `$pages[1]` - второй.
Перебор.

```
foreach($pages[1]->all() as $row){
  dd($row->all()); // вставляем в бд
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример получения данных с конкретного листа Excel документа

```
Excel::load($destinationPath . $filename, function($reader) use (&$excel) {
               $objExcel = $reader->getExcel();
               $sheet = $objExcel->getSheet(0);
               $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
               $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

               //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
               for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
               {
                  //  Read a row of data into an array
                  $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
                  $excel[] = $rowData[0];
               }
    });
```

А вот так можно перебрать все листы

```
Excel::load(MyExcelClass::getFile(), function ($reader) {
    foreach($reader as $sheet) // loop through sheets
    {
         $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
         $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

         //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
         for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
         {
             //  Read a row of data into an array
             $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
             $excel[] = $rowData[0];
         }
    }
});
```